# Tic Tac Toe algorithm using itertools

Tags: python, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, ai, iteration

I'm looking for feedback on the readability of my code and opinions on the pick_best algorithm. I do this stuff for fun when I have time, and never get a chance to have anyone else look at it. Hopefully, I can use this site to improve my coding.

```
from itertools import permutations 
from random import randint
class TTT:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.game_grid = [0 for x in range(9)]  
        self.winning_matrix = ((0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8), (0,3,6), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (0,4,8), (2,4,6))        

    def game_state(self, grid):
        '''Prints current game state'''
        print "\n\n\n0 1 2 \n3 4 5 \n6 7 8 \n"
        for square in range(9):
            if square%3==0: print
            print ['.', 'O', 'X'][grid[square]],
        print

    def check_game(self, grid):
        '''Checks game state for a winner or tie'''
        for row in self.winning_matrix:
            total = sum([grid[x] for x in row])
            if abs(total) == 3: 
                return self.winner_is(total)
        return self.winner_is(total)

    def winner_is(self, total):
        '''Establishes which player wins in current node'''
        return total/3 if abs(total)==3 else 0

    def pick_best(self):
        '''A non-recursive minimax style function utilizing itertools.permutations'''
        avail_squares = [pos for pos, x in enumerate(self.game_grid) if x==0] 
        score = {x:0 for x in avail_squares}    #keeps minimax score for current game state  
        for perm in permutations(avail_squares): #thank you itertools
            player = -1 #start with computer player
            node = list(self.game_grid) #node is a copy of the current game state
            for square in perm:
                node[square]=player #makes a move in the permutation
                state_score = self.check_game(node) #checks to see if anyone won
                if state_score: 
                    ''' if there is a winning play in this node,
                        a score based off the depth of the play is added
                        to the total score of the possible move.
                        Then we break out of the current permutation'''
                    score[perm[0]] += (10**(len(perm)-perm.index(square)))*-1*state_score 
                    break 
                player *= -1 #swaps to the next player in the node
        return max(score, key=lambda x: score[x]) #returns square with highest score      

    def player_choice(self):
        start = raw_input("Would you like to start? (Y/N) ")
        print start
        if start.upper() == 'Y':
            return False, 1
        elif start.upper() == 'N':
            return False, -1
        else:
            print "Please choose (Y)es or (N)o"
            return True, 0

    def pick_a_spot(self):
        move = raw_input("Where would you like to move 0-8? ")
        if move.isdigit() and 0<=int(move)<9:
            m = int(move)
            if self.game_grid[m] == 0:
                return False, m
        return True, 9


    def play(self):
        '''A very basic game play interface to test algorithm.'''
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            invalid, player = self.player_choice()
        if player == -1: 
            self.game_grid[randint(0,8)]=-1
            player = 1
        self.game_state(self.game_grid)
        while 0 in self.game_grid and self.check_game(self.game_grid)==0:
            if player == 1:
                invalid = True
                while invalid:
                    invalid, move = self.pick_a_spot()
                self.game_grid[move]=1
                player = -1
            else:
                move = self.pick_best()
                player = 1
                self.game_grid[move]=-1
            self.game_state(self.game_grid)


if __name__=='__main__':
    TTT().play()
```

Answer (score 1):

`TTT` is not a clear name, `TicTacToe` is only 6 characters more, and much clearer.

You should have `winning_matrix` be a constant, defined just inside the class declaration:

```
class TicTacToe:
    WINNING_MATRIX = ((0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8), (0,3,6), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (0,4,8), (2,4,6))
```

Indexing a literal is odd to see, you should declare the constant `ICONS` and index that.

```
ICONS = ['.', 'O', 'X']

...

print ICONS[grid[square]],
```

I personally prefer using `print('\n')` to make it more clear what's happening as it can look funny to see just a `print`. You also shouldn't use an inline `if` as they're very easy to misread.

```
if square % 3 == 0: print
print ['.', 'O', 'X'][grid[square]],
```

The above looks like the `if` is meant to apply to the print call beneath it, but has an indentation error. Even when you spot the `print`, it seems like that was put there accidentally because it doesn't seem to print anything.

```
if square % 3 == 0:
    print('\n')
print(ICONS[grid[square]])
```

Also, instead of iterating over numbers and using those to index you should iterate over `grid` itself. You need the index of the values to detect when to print a new line, but you can still do this using `enumerate`.

```
for index, square in enumerate(grid):
    if index % 3 == 0:
        print('\n')
    print(ICONS[square])
```

This is much simpler than a double index. Plus, if you were to change the size of `grid` for any reason, you'd then be able to handle it just fine. The one last change, particularly in that case, could be to replace the 3 with a constant like `ROW_WIDTH`.

You could also make functions a lot clearer, like this:

```
def winner_is(self, total):
    '''Establishes which player wins in current node'''
    return total/3 if abs(total)==3 else 0
```

Your docstring is vague, and more abstract than it should be. Tell me what the function does, not what it's for.

```
def winner_is(self, total):
    '''Returns -1 or 1 to indicate which player won, or 0 for a tie.'''
```

However what's odd is that you're doubling down on your check for if the total is 3? You're calling `self.winner_is` when you've already determined that the total is three, or when it's definitely a tie. I'd combine the functions into one:

```
def check_game(self, grid):
    '''Returns -1 or 1 to indicate which player won, or 0 for a tie.'''

    for row in self.winning_matrix:
        total = sum([grid[x] for x in row])
        if abs(total) == 3: 
            return total / 3
    return 0
```

Now it's much simpler and contained, but still does exactly the same. I'd also consider renaming this, as it's unclear what a check would do, or what aspect of the game it applies to. `eval_winner` could improve the clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're completely right about the winner_is() function being useless. I'm not sure how that got past my refactoring. I thought indexing the literal [',','O','X'] was pretty cool but I like your suggestion better. Same with making the list winning_matrix a constant. I never would have come up with that one on my own. Any thoughts on the function pick_best()?